# How to change image according to the color on homepage

Tags: configurable-product

I get the configurable products on homepage and now i have to add a color slider at the bottom of the image so than when i click on the particular color the image of the product can change accordingly.
Can anyone please help me how can i do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far, any approach you've taken you want to share with us? this question is quite broad

Comment: well I have got success in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to swap the images around with Javascript. This will be a whole lot easier if each of your "big" product images are given a unique ID, so add something like this to those images:

```
id="bigger_image_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>
```

Then you're going to want a way of retrieving all of the simple products (i.e. all of the colour options for each product). You'll need to loop through each colour and output the small thumbnail, but also give that image some attributes that will help the javascript know which images to swap out when it's clicked:

```
<?php $configurable = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_product_collection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
foreach($simple_product_collection as $simple_product)  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($simple_product, 'image', $simple_product->getImage())->resize(100, 100);?>" 
    data-bigger-image="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($simple_product, 'image', $simple_product->getImage())->resize(200, 200);?>"
    data-target-image="bigger_image_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
    class="colour_image"
    alt="<?php echo $simple_product->getName(); ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The javascript for creating the behaviour of these images should be pretty straight forward. If you're using jQuery, then it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('colour_image').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('data-target-image')).src($(this).attr('data-bigger-image'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: yeah thanks I already got that work. I also use this jquery function.

Comment: Glad to hear that great minds think alike. Good luck with the rest of your project. Would you mind marking one of the answers as "accepted" if you've now managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Well thanks a lot, I really needs lots of "Good Lucks" right now.
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

## draft

Add a picture for every color with a known name, like `<sku>_<colorname|hexcode|whatever|>` and then add a few lines of JS to the page which gets the current ima,e cuts the colorname and adds the new one.